# use quotes around property in an object

Tags: javascript

Recently I saw this method of declaring properties within an object:

```
var o = {

     "first_prop": "first",
     "secon_prop": "secon"

}
```

with each within quotes, instead of like I have always seen before

```
var o = {

     first_prop: "first",
     secon_prop: "secon"

}
```

Both dot and bracket syntax seem to work when referring to these properties. Is there any practical advantage of one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One main difference between the two is being valid JSON. Within JSON all key names must be strings.

Another difference is being able to use keywords as keys.

For instance you can't use `class: 1` in either JavaScript or JSON, but you *can* use `"class": 1`

Answer (score 4):

The only practical difference is that strings can include characters that identifiers cannot.